# Extract text from string generated from selected endnotes

Tags: vba, ms-word, extract

In Word, when I select a paragraph, I need a MsgBox to display a list (i.e. a new line for each) of a certain section within an endnote.

The below code will display a MsgBox with the FULL TEXT of endnotes within the selection, but I only want the information between the phrase "Extracted material is from " and the next semicolon to be listed in the MsgBox. (Example below of endnotes with desired extraction in bold)

Endnote Format:

[1] Position1text; Position2text; Position3text; Position4text; Position5text; Position6 Extracted material is from **EDIBLE//FRUIT//APPPLES**; Position7text; Position8text

[2] Position1text; Position2text; Position3text; Position4text; Position5text; Position6 Extracted material is from **NONEDIBLE//FURNITURE//CHAIR**; Position7text; Position8text

I'd like the MsgBox to read:

This paragraph contains:

EDIBLE//FRUIT//APPPLES

NONEDIBLE//FURNITURE//CHAIR

```
Sub TestEndNoteMsg()
Dim e As Endnote
Dim str As String
For Each e In Selection.Endnotes
    str = str & e.Range.Text
Next e
MsgBox str
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not optimized so that you can better see how this works. You can just as easily nest the `InStr` functions into a single line, but it gets a little hard to follow.

Below you can see that you first find the position of the phrase "Extracted material is from " and add 27 characters to the position (the length of the string - 1). That gives us the character position we want to start the extraction from.

Then using this position as a new starting point, find the next semi-colon and save that position in `lngEnd`. Then transform `str` to extract only the data you want.

**Edit**
Forgot the loop, I am protecting `str` until the parsed string is created, then appending each element to the variable. I changed `str` to `e.Range.Text` to deal only with the current endnote processing and avoiding truncating the previous endnote.

```
Sub TestEndNoteMsg()
Dim e As Endnote
Dim str As String
Dim lngStart As Long
Dim lngEnd As Long
For Each e In Selection.Endnotes
    lngStart = InStr(1, e.Range.Text, "Extracted material is from ", 1) + 27
    lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, e.Range.Text, ";", 1)
    str = str & MID(e.Range.Text, lngStart, lngEnd - lngStart) & vbcrlf
Next e
MsgBox "This paragraph contains:" & vbcrlf & str
End Sub
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks Christopher - I tried the above code but got a Runtime Error 13: Type Mismatch and the debugger highlighted this line:                       
lngStart = InStr(1, e.Range.Text, "Extracted material is from " + 28, 1)

Comment: Sorry, not sure what I was thinking. I have updated the code.

Comment: Christopher, that worked but it is putting "Extracted material is from" in the MsgBox instead of just the EDIBLE//FRUIT//APPPLES. It's also not putting each extraction on a new line in the MsgBox.

Comment: Hm, that's weird, did you copy the latest update? It works great for me.

Comment: Got it - the problem exists between keyboard and chair...bad hand jamming btw two machines. Solved! Thanks for your help

Comment: Christopher - upon further testing (in another "real" document) this appears to extract and list for ALL endnotes, not just the selected endnotes. The "real" document I'm testing on has 18 endnotes - and despite selecting just the first paragraph (which contains endnotes 1 and 2) it displays all 18. You've been graciuous with your time, so appreciate any final assistance you could provide.

Comment: Hm there must be a problem with `Selection` which isn't much of a surprise. I will have to think about this and get back to you.

Comment: I can't seem to limit the endnotes collection. I looked through documentation but cannot find a property that would identify the location of an endpoint to test whether it intersects with the selection. Sorry, I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Christopher - you're the real MVP for sticking with me this long, thanks for the help. If I find a solution I will post here