# Loop through, extract text from endnotes and append comment to end-note source paragraph

Tags: arrays, vba, string, ms-word

This is a follow up to a previous question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47076277/extract-text-from-string-generated-from-selected-endnotes). Basically I repeatedly need to extract certain text from endnotes. This text always follows the phrase "Extracted material is from " and is followed by a ;.

In my previous method, I had to manually select each paragraph (slow/cumbersome) and I the msgbox became problematic, as I sometimes want to scroll in the doc to check something.

Therefore, I would prefer a comment be added to the paragraph instead. So I made some modifications, but it seems the below code is ignoring the selection, and adds the extracted text from my **ALL the endnotes in the document** to the comment box, rather than only the endnotes associated with the selected paragraph.

What am I doing wrong?

*Secondarily, and less important for now, is that eventually I would like to be able to compare the values returned in the str variable to one another, as there is a (somewhat arcane) hierarchy. Could these strings be written to a temporary array for each paragraph and compared to a dictionary (that would define the hierarchy) or something?*

```
Sub EndNotes_Comment_Each_Paragraph_Loop()
Dim e As Endnote
Dim str As String
Dim lngStart As Long
Dim lngEnd As Long
Dim pCount As Long
Dim i As Long

pCount = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

For i = 1 To pCount
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Select
str = ""
    For Each e In Selection.Endnotes
        lngStart = InStr(1, e.Range.Text, "Extracted material is from ", 1) + 27
        lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, e.Range.Text, ";", 1)
        str = str & Mid(e.Range.Text, lngStart, lngEnd - lngStart) & vbCrLf
    Next e
ActiveDocument.Comments.Add Selection.Range, Text:="This paragraph contains:" & vbCrLf & str
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but apparently Word picks up all the endnotes when `Range.Endnotes` is addressed. This can be countered by checking whether an endnote's `Reference` (that's the superscript number in the text) is in the same `Range` as the paragraph being processed:

```
 If e.Reference.InRange(para.Range) Then
```

It's also important to only create a comment if a paragraph contains endnotes. For this a `Boolean` is declared and set to `True` if the paragraph contains an endnote. It's reset to `False` when looping to the next paragraph.

This code uses `For Each` to loop all the paragraphs in the document instead of using a "counter" in a `For` loop. It should be more efficient, but the approach in the question also works. Also, use of `Selection` is avoided. That's also more efficient and less error-prone. Instead, the paragraph's `Range` is used.

```
Sub EndNotes_Comment_Each_Paragraph_Loop()
    Dim e As Endnote
    Dim str As String
    Dim lngStart As Long
    Dim lngEnd As Long
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph, rngPara As Word.Range
    Dim isE As Boolean

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.paragraphs
        str = ""
        isE = False
        Set rngPara = para.Range
        For Each e In rngPara.Endnotes
            If e.Reference.InRange(rngPara) Then
                lngStart = InStr(1, e.Range.text, "Extracted material is from ", 1) + 27
                lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, e.Range.text, ";", 1)
                str = str & Mid(e.Range.text, lngStart, lngEnd - lngStart) & vbCrLf
                isE = True
            End If
        Next e
        If isE Then
            ActiveDocument.Comments.Add rngPara, "This paragraph contains:" & vbCrLf & str
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That did it perfectly, thank you (Thank you again, you've helped me multiple times now!)

Answer (score -1):

You can't add comments to endnotes or footnotes. To add comments to the corresponding endnote reference paragraphs, try the following code, which is also much more efficient than your own:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Const StrPre As String = "Extracted material is from"
Const StrCmt As String = "This paragraph contains:"
With ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdEndnotesStory)
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = StrPre & "*;"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .Parent.Comments.Add Range:=.Endnotes(1).Reference.Paragraphs(1).Range, _
      Text:=StrCmt & Split(Split(.Text, StrPre)(1), ";")(0)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do NOT want to add comments to endnotes or footnotes. **I want to add comments (containing the extracted text) to the paragraph with which the endnote is associated**. What I don't understand is why my code pulls in extracted text from ALL paragraphs into a comment box instead of just the endnotes for that paragraph.

Comment: @kroy2008 In that case, the problem is with your original description of the task at hand. It was by no means clear from what you posted that that is what you wanted to do. Try the revised code.

Comment: Thanks for the revsions. I guess I could have been more clear in my original question.

*"So I made some modifications, but it seems the below code is ignoring the selection, and adds the extracted text from my ALL the endnotes in the document to the comment box, **rather than only the endnotes associated with the selected paragraph**"*